# What Chinese characters for “ching wong but jeep” (Roughly: There is no one to keep things going)?

Tags: transliteration

[Man Sing Lee of Mott 32](https://www.theloophk.com/hong-kong-chef-bio-man-sing-lee-of-mott-32/)

> So Toronto and Vancouver’s Chinese food culture is starting to be “**ching wong but jeep**” (Roughly: There is no one to keep things going). Toronto and Vancouver used to compete in the quality of their Chinese restaurants, but nowadays they only compete in how cheap and how large their dishes are — kind of how Hong Kong was back in the day.

What Chinese characters do “**ching wong but jeep**” mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the pronunciation along, I guess it is 青黄不接 （qing1 huang2 bu4 jie1）

青：green, which means the newly planted still growing wheat this year

黄：yellow, which means the old wheat gathered last year

不接：ends does not meet

青黄不接：the old wheat is almost gone but the new wheat is still growing: there is nothing to eat in the period in between. It generally means the old things are gone but new things are still not seen in the near future.

In your example, it might mean the old chefs are retiring but the new chefs are still not qualified enough. As a result, the food quality is decaying.

Comment: The [Cantonese pronunciation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%9D%92%E9%BB%83%E4%B8%8D%E6%8E%A5#Chinese), at least in Guangdong, is cing1 wong4 bat1 zip3 in Jyutping and /t͡sʰɪŋ⁵⁵ wɔːŋ²¹ pɐt̚⁵ t͡siːp̚³/ in IPA.